# Internet explorer ignoring cookies

Tags: internet-explorer, cookies, tomcat7

I have read about similar problems but almost all of them are related with *two-letter domains* and *underscore*. Not my case. I am working with Intranet so no problems regarding domain name. Also, if I try it with domain name instead IP (thinking that maybe IE do not trust my IP) the problem is still there.

Let me summarize some facts:

- No two-letter domains problem.
- No underscore problem.
- Not working in Intranet 10.* (HTTP and HTTPS) but working in 172.* and local.
- Not a firewall problem. I have tested it without firewall, pointing directly to the server (Tomcat 7.0.42)
- Problem is just with IE (tested with IE7 to IE11). Working with Chrome and Firefox.
- Not a cookie path problem. I have forced cookie path using 'sessionCookiePath'. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html
- Not slash problem. I have set 'sessionCookiePathUsesTrailingSlash' to false and true.
- Tomcat is sending all the time the cookie in the response header but no cookie in the request header.
- Not working even if I use the public URL to reach the server(HTTPS URL with verisign certificate).
- I have configured IE to accept cookies and add my site as trusted sites.
- I have even downloaded tomcat installation in the 10. server and run it into my local. It works.
- With Firefox, if, with firebug, configured to deny cookies from my site, behaviour is the same. Servers sends a new cookie any time.

Here the request header (I click in the login button):

```
Solicitar   POST /admin/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1
Accept  application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer https://10.45.17.2/admin/login
Accept-Language es-ES
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    10.45.17.2
Content-Length  57
DNT 1
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
```

Response header

```
Respuesta   HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Date    Mon, 17 Nov 2014 10:21:18 GMT
Server  Apache
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=FA5205FEA416706667A0F309465AEA61.nodo2; Version=1; Path="/admin/"; Secure; HttpOnly
Location    https://10.45.17.2/admin/start
Content-Length  0
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

User is logged, but server application takes the user again to login page:

Request header:

```
Solicitar   POST /admin/j_spring_security_check HTTP/1.1
Accept  application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer https://10.45.17.2/admin/login
Accept-Language es-ES
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    10.45.17.2
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
DNT 1
Solicitar   GET /admin/start HTTP/1.1
Accept  application/x-ms-application, image/jpeg, application/xaml+xml, image/gif, image/pjpeg, application/x-ms-xbap, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint, application/msword, */*
Referer https://10.45.17.2/admin/login
Accept-Language es-ES
User-Agent  Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.2; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Host    10.45.17.2
Connection  Keep-Alive
Cache-Control   no-cache
DNT 1
```

Responser reader:

```
Respuesta   HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Date    Mon, 17 Nov 2014 10:21:18 GMT
Server  Apache
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=2F868BF115F960E72E1F5ED0DDDD7B19.nodo1; Version=1; Path="/admin/"; Secure; HttpOnly
Location    https://10.45.17.2/admin/login
Content-Length  0
Connection  close
Content-Type    text/plain; charset=UTF-8
```

You can see how server sends a different cookie. It happens for all request.

Also, note that I am working with Struts2 and Spring Security.

Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, problem has been solved. The problems was the double quoutes in the session path. Setting the system properties `FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR` to false fix the problem.

`-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.http.ServerCookie.FWD_SLASH_IS_SEPARATOR=false`

Some doc: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/Cookies